# MediaPlayer Error (1, -1004)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have searched too much here on stack overflow but I am unable to find any solution of my problem.

I am getting a Media Player Error named 'MEDIA_ERROR_IO' code -1004.

I am stream an audio from server everything works good. song prepared and then starts in **onPrepared()** method.

Now the problem comes when there is an incoming call and phone starts ringing, and I pauses the song by calling **mediaPlayer.pause()** from my BroadcastReceiver class.

when the Phone call ends start the audio again by calling **mediaPlayer.start()**

the audio starts but after 2-3 seconds it stops with an Error that is MediaPlayer error (1, -1004).

***Now What should I do?***

Any Help is appreciable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the audio starts but after 2-3 seconds it stops with an Error that is
>   MediaPlayer error (1, -1004).

First, Lets understand what error (1, -1004) means. -1004 is the error code for IO error. Below reference from MediaPlayer.java source code.

```
/** File or network related operation errors. */
public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_IO = -1004;
```

This type of error comes if for some reason, the media player is not able to connect to the server due to network issues. It could be bad internet connectivity at that instance or some network related reason due which the media player was unable to connect to the server. There are some other similar error codes that the media player can throw like time-outs or server died:

```
/** Some operation takes too long to complete, usually more than 3-5 seconds. */
    public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT = -110;
/** Media server died.*/
    public static final int MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED = 100;
```

> Now What should I do?

To handle errors generated by media player at run time, you should implement Error Listener. You can handle the error in which ever way as you like for example restart the player.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                switch(extra){
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                        // Do Something
                        // eg. reset the media player and restart
                        break;
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO:
                        // Do Something
                        // eg. Show dialog to user indicating bad connectivity
                        // or attempt to restart the player
                        break;
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT:
                        //Do Something
                        //eg. Show dialog that there was error in connecting to the server
                        // or attempt some retries
                        break;
                }
                //You must always return true if you want the error listener to work
                return true;
            }
        });
```